# Grails webapp not displaying gsp page

Tags: grails, gsp

I am having some issues displaying a .gsp file and I am not quite sure as to why. I have the following code:

```
class UrlMappings{
    static mappings = {
        "/"(controller: 'index', action: 'index')
    }
}

class IndexController{
    def index(){
        render(view: "index")
    } 
}
```

And then in grails-app/views/index I have index.gsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

When I hit http://localhost:8080/ I get a 500 status code error. If, however, I change the IndexController to have

```
render "Hello World"
```

it will display "Hello World", so the app seems to be launching.

Does anyone know what's going on? Part of the stacktrace:

```
17:09:40.677 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name '/index/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/index/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
```

Comment: Seems strange. Just make sure you have run the classic `grails clean` along with a Grails runtime restart.

Comment: Avoid using names that has specific meaning in the framework. If you change Index to something else, do you get the same error?

Comment: Also wouldn't `http://host/index/index` look just a little wrong ? anyhow how about "/index"(controller: 'aha',  action:"nice" )    that then  redirect `/index` to some other controller action you could write it for `/index/index` too but think it just looks a little odd people start to question skills of developer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because of `Grails` is not able to find out the location of your view.

> Well avoid the names which have some predefined context in the framework(Just an suggestion not an problem in your case).
>
> As you have used the `index` for controller change it to something else

So in your case when you will hit the `URL` http://localhost:8080/ your `URLMapping` will redirect it to your controllers `index` action and it will render the corresponding view.

Like below

```
class UrlMappings{
    static mappings = {
        "/"(controller: 'provision', action: 'index')
    }
}

class ProvisionController{

    def index(){ 
        // You don't really need to render it grails will render
        // it automatically as our view has same name as action
        render(view: "index")   
    } 
}
```

And then in `grails-app/views/provision/` create `index.gsp`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

**You were adding the view at wrong location `grails-app/views/index.gsp` move it to `grails-app/views/provision/index.gsp`**

> Renamed your `IndexController` to `ProvisionController` in above example.

Comment: Hello Prakash, thanks for your answer. I managed to figure it why it was behaving as it was. I don't believe I had it in the wrong location, as I had index.gsp in grails-app/views/index/. The reason I think it wasn't working was because in build.gradle I had set profile "org.grails.profiles:rest-api" instead of :web (when I first started my little project I was only interested in API functionality, and not worried about a front end)